# Generate a new set of points along a line

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics, geometry

I have a Python project where I need to redraw a line many times with the points in random places but keeping the line's shape and point count roughly the same. The final output will be using polygonal points and **not** Bezier paths (though I wouldn't be opposed to using Bezier as an intermediary step).

This animation is demonstrating how the points could move along the line to different positions while maintaining the general shape.
[image: Point Count animation]

I also have a working example below where I'm moving along the line and picking random new points between existing points (the red line, below). It works okay, but I'd love to hear some other approaches I might take if someone knows of a better one?

*Though this code is using `matplotlib` to demonstrate the line, the final program will not.*

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import random
from random import (randint,uniform)

def move_along_line(p1, p2, scalar):
    distX = p2[0] - p1[0]
    distY = p2[1] - p1[1]

    modX = (distX * scalar) + p1[0]
    modY = (distY * scalar) + p1[1]

    return [modX, modY]

x_coords = [213.5500031,234.3809357,255.211853,276.0427856,296.8737183,317.7046204,340.1997681,364.3751221,388.5505066,414.8896484,444.5192261,478.5549622,514.5779419,545.4779053,570.3830566,588.0241699,598.2469482,599.772583,596.758728,593.7449341,590.7310791,593.373291,610.0373535,642.1326294,677.4451904,710.0697021,737.6887817,764.4020386,791.1152954,817.8284912,844.541687,871.2550049,897.9682007,924.6813965,951.3945923,978.1078491,1009.909546,1042.689941,1068.179199,1089.543091]
y_coords = [487.3099976,456.8832703,426.4565125,396.0297852,365.6030273,335.1763,306.0349426,278.1913452,250.3477478,224.7166748,203.0908051,191.2358704,197.6810608,217.504303,244.4946136,276.7698364,312.0551453,348.6885986,385.4395447,422.1904297,458.9414063,495.5985413,527.0128479,537.1477661,527.6642456,510.959259,486.6988525,461.2799683,435.8611145,410.4422913,385.023468,359.6045532,334.18573,308.7669067,283.3480835,257.929184,239.4429474,253.6099091,280.1803284,310.158783]
plt.plot(x_coords,y_coords,color='b')
plt.scatter(x_coords,y_coords,s=2)

new_line_x = []
new_line_y = []

for tgt in range(len(x_coords)-1):
    #tgt = randint(0, len(x_coords)-1)
    next_pt = tgt+1
    new_pt = move_along_line([x_coords[tgt],y_coords[tgt]], [x_coords[next_pt],y_coords[next_pt]], uniform(0, 1))
    new_line_x.append(new_pt[0])
    new_line_y.append(new_pt[1])

plt.plot(new_line_x,new_line_y,color='r')
plt.scatter(new_line_x,new_line_y,s=10)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is your input data points? Or is it something else?

Comment: Hi @BrendanOtherwhyz , thanks for the reply. The input will be points with `x` and `y` coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the most optimal way to do this but essentially you want to follow these steps:

Calculate the distance of the entire path, and the distance between all the points. Then for each point, tally the distances to that point.

Generate a new set of random points along the path starting with 0, then for each pair of points calculate a random distance: random value between 0 and 1 * total length of the path.

Sort these distances from smallest to largest.

For each random distance loop over the distances find the index where the random distance is > than distance i, and less than distance i+1. Interpolate new x and y values from these points.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import numpy
import random
import math

x_coords = [195.21,212.53,237.39,270.91,314.21,368.43,434.69,514.1,607.8,692.69,746.98,773.8,776.25,757.45,720.52,668.55,604.68,545.37,505.79,487.05,490.27,516.58,567.09,642.93,745.2,851.5,939.53,1010.54,1065.8,1106.58,1134.15,1149.75,1154.68]
y_coords = [195.34,272.27,356.59,438.98,510.14,560.76,581.52,563.13,496.27,404.39,318.83,242.15,176.92,125.69,91.02,75.48,81.62,113.49,168.57,239.59,319.29,400.38,475.6,537.67,579.32,586.78,558.32,504.7,436.69,365.05,300.55,253.95,236.03]
n_points = 100
x_coords = numpy.array(x_coords)
x_min = x_coords.min()
x_max = x_coords.max()
x_range = x_max - x_min
distances = []
tallied_distances = [0]
tallied_distance = 0
for i in range(0, len(x_coords) -1):
    xi = x_coords[i]
    xf = x_coords[i + 1]
    yi= y_coords[i]
    yf = y_coords[i+1]
    d = math.sqrt((xf-xi)**2 + (yf-yi)**2)
    tallied_distance += d
    tallied_distances.append(tallied_distance)
random_distances_along_line = [0]
for i in range(0, n_points-2):
    random_distances_along_line.append(random.random()*tallied_distance)
random_distances_along_line.sort()
new_x_points = [x_coords[0]]
new_y_points = [y_coords[0]]
for i in range(0, len(random_distances_along_line)):
    dt = random_distances_along_line[i]
    for j in range(0, len(tallied_distances)-1):
        di = tallied_distances[j]
        df = tallied_distances[j+1]
        if di < dt and dt < df:
            difference = dt - di
            xi = x_coords[j]
            xf = x_coords[j+1]
            yi = y_coords[j]
            yf = y_coords[j+1]
            xt = xi+(xf-xi)*difference/(df-di)
            yt = yi+(yf-yi)*difference/(df-di)
            new_x_points.append(xt)
            new_y_points.append(yt)
new_x_points.append(x_coords[len(x_coords)-1])
new_y_points.append(y_coords[len(y_coords)-1])
plt.plot(new_x_points, new_y_points)
plt.scatter(new_x_points, new_y_points,s=2)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Brendan! Would you mind explaining how the y interpolation is working? Does `interp1d` move points along a line similar to the `move_along_line` function in my example? Would your code work if the line curved back upon itself like in this image? Thank you! https://imgur.com/a/poQ0rzO

Comment: The interpolation algorithm takes the target x position and looks for an exact match in the x points, if there is no match it takes the closest points to the left and right and interpolates. The index of the x points is used to get the y values. Then you have y = yi + (yf-yi)*(xt-xi)/(xf-xi). Where i is the initial (left side), f is the final (right side), and t is the target. Apologies, I overlooked this aspect. Unfortunately, this won't work for a curve which has multiple y values for any x value. In that case you need another approach. One that will considers the distance along the path.

Comment: I've updated my answer to account for this case.

Comment: Wow, thank you! It seems to work, however the first few points seem to be flattened?
Here is an example with your code: https://trinket.io/python3/be18d9c48c
Here is one with my approach (to show the line's shape is not flat): https://trinket.io/python3/0ef58b31cb

Comment: I see, that was an index issue. I've done a little fix and refactor. Please take a look